# MS Access SQL Forcing values where none exist

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, aggregation, iif

To summarize, I am splitting Weekly digital marketing revenue into percent of total based on Channel/BU/Order_Store/Item_Store balance of sales to create ratios.

The dilemma of this equation is that if there is a missing ratio due to non existent sales in a given channel/BU/Order_Store/Item_Store/Week, my spend query will multiply by zero, which will understate spend. If this is the case, I need to force the spend into "Sears" Item_Store by BU balance of Sales. I am at a crossroads so to speak with translating this solution into sql coding:

### Creating the Ratios

```
SELECT a.*, CDbl(a.Revenue / b.Revenue) AS Ratios

FROM 

(SELECT buc.FY, buc.FM, buc.FW, buc.Rept_Chnl, buc.BU_NM,
IIf(buc.Order_Store="SEARS","Desktop","Mobile") AS Platform, buc.Item_Store, SUM(buc.Revenue) AS Revenue 
FROM tbl_BUChannelReporting AS buc 
WHERE buc.order_Store in ("SEARS","MG:SRS")  
AND buc.Item_Store <> "MKTPL" 
GROUP BY buc.FY, buc.FM, buc.FW, buc.Rept_Chnl, buc.BU_NM, IIf(buc.Order_Store="SEARS","Desktop","Mobile"), buc.Item_Store 
HAVING SUM(buc.Revenue) <> 0)  AS a 

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT buc.FY, buc.FM, buc.FW, buc.Rept_Chnl, buc.BU_NM, IIf(buc.Order_Store="SEARS","Desktop","Mobile") AS Platform, SUM(buc.Revenue) AS Revenue 
FROM tbl_BUChannelReporting AS buc 
WHERE buc.order_Store in ("SEARS","MG:SRS")  AND buc.Item_Store <> "MKTPL" 
GROUP BY buc.FY, buc.FM, buc.FW, buc.Rept_Chnl, buc.BU_NM, IIf(buc.Order_Store="SEARS","Desktop","Mobile") 
HAVING SUM(buc.Revenue) <> 0)  AS b 

ON (a.FY = b.FY) 
AND (a.FM = b.FM) 
AND (a.FW = b.FW) 
AND (a.Rept_Chnl = b.Rept_Chnl) 
AND (a.BU_NM = b.BU_NM) 
AND (a.Platform = b.Platform);
```

### Multiplying Spend By Ratios (from prior query)

```
SELECT b.FY, b.FM, b.FW, b.Omniture_Channel, b.BU_NM, b.Platform, b.item_store, cdbl(b.Ratios * a.Spend) AS Spend

FROM 

(SELECT s.FY, s.FM, s.FW, s.Omniture_Channel, s.BU_NM, s.Platform, sum(s.Spend) AS Spend 
FROM spend_kmart AS s 
GROUP BY s.FY, s.FM, s.FW, s.Omniture_Channel, s.BU_NM, s.Platform 
HAVING SUM(s.Spend) <> 0)  AS a 

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT val(i.FY) AS FY, i.FM, i.FW, i.Rept_Chnl AS Omniture_Channel, i.BU_NM, i.Platform, i.item_store, cdbl(i.Ratios) AS Ratios 
FROM qry_Item_Store_Ratios_KMT_Non_MKTPL AS i 
GROUP BY val(i.FY), i.FM, i.FW, i.Rept_Chnl, i.BU_NM, i.Platform, i.item_store, cdbl(i.Ratios))  AS b 

ON (a.FY = b.FY) 
AND (a.FM = b.FM) 
AND (a.FW = b.FW) 
AND (a.Omniture_Channel = b.Omniture_Channel) 
AND (a.BU_NM = b.BU_NM) 
AND (a.Platform = b.Platform);
```

- One additional note is that in the 1st query, I added the "HAVING SUM(buc.Revenue) <> 0" clause because I was getting NUM & Div/0 errors.

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzDRm.png)

Thanks in advance for your time and take care!

-D

Comment: Please clarify: *I need to force the spend into "Sears" Item_Store by BU balance of Sales*...feel free to illustrate with data.

Comment: Hello Parfait, my apologies I was unclear in describing my issue - I have edited this post to include an image showing two examples - One where the input matches the output total and the second where there is an issue because there is no ratio available to multiply spend to. Of course anything times zero is zero. I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly allocate the spend in this type of situation, but it can't simply disappear as it would be understated cost to said BU.

Comment: I understand your problem. I just don't understand your solution. Is there a *Balance of Sales* field?

Comment: There is a 'Ratios' field (aka Balance of Sales field) created from the first of 2 queries above, but I felt there was no need to show the ratios. If this is required for the solution, then of course that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Query can't create data that doesn't exist. If you need to show all combinations of channel/BU/Order_Store/Item_Store/Week even if there is no data then need a dataset of all possible combinations of channel/BU/Order_Store/Item_Store/Week. If you have a table for each of these elements, including the Weeks, this dataset can be created by query including them. This query would not have any JOIN clauses which results in every record of each table associating with each record of other tables - a Cartesian product query. Beware, the more tables involved the slower the query. Then join this query to the sales data table.

Or another approach would be 52 textboxes with DSum() function. I have used this approach to build a simple report showing 12 months of summarized data. I wanted every month to display even if there was no data.